# Code completion candidates displayed in minibuffer

Tags: completion, minibuffer

How can I get the completion candidates to be displayed in the minibuffer (see e.g. here https://tuhdo.github.io/static/c-ide/semantic-boost-demo.gif) instead of being displayed at the cursor? The setup in the link uses `company` and `helm`. I'd like to keep it if possible.